# How to plot 'outside' of the a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have values 1 through 5000 along the x-axis and percentage along the y-axis, however, I only want the values from 1-150 to be visible along the x-axis (in order to make the scale more usable), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Originally, I was just excluding the data with values over 150, but that obviously doesn't work with percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by limiting the range of the x-axis (or y-axis) of the plot: [`plt.xlim(1, 150)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) or [`ax.set_xlim(1, 150)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html).

Comment: Perfect, Thanks.